# How to make sure that Draggable component do not go ouside the Dropable Area or some specific div in react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd, sortablejs, react-sortable-hoc

How to make sure that Draggable component do not go ouside the Dropable Area or some specific div in react-beautiful-dnd??

I want to make sure that the draggable component do not go outside of some specific div or area or outside dropable area.

In current time I could not find any work around to restrict the movement of Draggable component in some specific area or container. Any help and suggestion in most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-sortable-hoc` for this. It lets you lock your sortableElement to stay in the sortableContainer by passing `lockToContainerEdges` to the HOC. `react-beautiful-dnd` also has one big limitation that it only works in one direction i.e either horizontally or vertically but with `react-sortable-hoc` you can pass `axis='xy'` to the `sortableContainer` HOC and it lets you sort in a grid.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.